# How to intentionally fail a job in kubernetes?

Tags: java, containers, docker-swarm, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I have an image of java code that does database validation and the job uses that image. I want the job to intentionally fail when the database validation fails. Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: Returning exit code != 0 didn't work for you?

Comment: Do you mean System.exit(1) in java code? @rkosegi

Comment: Worked, thank you @rkosegi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Kubernetes job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/) is just a contrainer running. As with any container, the final exit code determines if the run was successful or not. So, to make your job fail you need to exit with a code other than 0.

How would you do this in Java?

```
System.exit(1)
```

How would you do this in Bash scripting?

```
exit 1
```

How would you do this in Node.js?

```
process.exit(1)
```

How would you do this in Python/PHP?

```
exit(1)
```

How would you do this in Go?

```
os.Exit(1)
```

Comment: I tried both `process.exit(0)` and `node index.js ; exit $?`, but the job keeps running until `activeDeadlineSeconds` was hit and terminated as a failure...